# Is it good to work in a funded PhD project to complete it within time?

Tags: phd, research-process, funding

I have enrolled my PhD in a German institute. The project is proposed by the institute and funding is by another agency. Based on my master work, I got selected for PhD. The proposed PhD work is not related to my M.Tech work. The application is different but the fundamentals are same. The project is funded for a limited period. The supervisor there has given me a research paper to follow.

May I know what is the probability to complete it within that time. Moreover, what sort of guidance I should expect expect from him.

Any necessary and advice in this regard would be highly appreciated and acknowledged.

Kind regards,
Manish

Answer (score 1):

> May I know what is the probability to complete it within that time. Moreover, what sort of guidance I should expect expect from him.

The answers will differ greatly based upon individual factors. Your primary source of information will be your advisor and your fellow PhD students and other researchers in your institute.

Some general points with respect to your questions, though:

- Whether or not you can complete your PhD by the time your funding ends may or may not be relevant. Your advisor may be able and also willing to arrange for or help you get some other funding after your project has ended.
- The project *itself* (i.e. the tasks mandated in the funding contract or similar documents) is probably feasible in time; especially as such documents are often kept a bit vague to allow for enough flexibility to finish things in time *and* work on your PhD.
- It is difficult to say now whether your own research and your project are different, especially if they are somewhat related. They might remain separate, or either of them might become much more aligned with the other than it seems now.
- The guidance to expect is very much dependent on the advisor and their resources. Maybe you will have weekly meetings, maybe you will have a hard time catching him to even read manuscripts before submission. Maybe he will advise himself, maybe he will delegate that to his postdocs or senior PhD candidates - or expect you to turn to them on your own.

Comment: A point to add is that depending on a country, PhD time may be limited regardless of funding. This is the case, e.g., in the UK and in France and isn't a bad thing by itself.

Comment: @AlexeyB.: Ah, true - I did not think of that because in my place and subfield, funded projects often run for 2 to 3 years, whereas the upper doctoral candidacy time limits (both the rule-based ones and the ones imposed by supervisors, who will then start saying things like "You should really look into completing your thesis and do nothing else now.") is somewhere at 5 to 6 years.